# Issue in using like operator on find for Integer data type in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose

I am having issue in constructing where query in Mongoose for integer data type. The key facevalue is integer data type. When i do find query something like this

Here's the code

```
var orCondition = 
[{
    facevalue: {
        '$regex': param,
        $options: 'i'
    }
}]

var data = await Product.find({
    $or: orCondition,
});
```

I am getting the below given error

`Cast to number failed for value "i" (type string) at path "facevalue" for model "product"`

What is the mistake i am doing on constructing orCondition and how can i fix this?

Comment: What is the expected result for "like" for integer? Do you want to cast it to a string?

Comment: Your question is very strange because you are trying to add `$regex` for the integer field.
What's the expected `data` ? Also what exactly you are trying to find?

Comment: @sachin i am trying to use like operator to search facevalue

Comment: @nimrodserok As facevalue is integere data type, if i enter `.5` it shold return values like 4.5 etc.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is using `$regexMatch`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $regexMatch: {
           input: {$toString: "$facevalue"},
          regex: ".5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lZ9ntNidauv)

Comment: It seems working good. great thanks, i will try it out with much examples