# Integer value partial search in aggregate MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregation

```
  const result = await locationModel.aggregate(
          [
            {$match : {uid : Number(uid), nid: {$regex:listing_id}}},
            {$sort : {[order_by]:order=='desc'?-1:1}},
            {$skip : skip},
            {$limit : pagelimit}
          ])
```

Here I have used regex method for partial search, but regex method only filter the string, but I need to filter out integer value. Please help me to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue in using like operator on find for Integer data type in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73618819/issue-in-using-like-operator-on-find-for-integer-data-type-in-mongoose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  
const result = await locationModel.aggregate(
          [
            {$match : {uid : Number(uid), '$expr': {'$regexMatch': {
            'input': { '$toString': { '$toLong': "$nid" } },
            'regex': listing_id
          }
        }}},
            {$sort : {[order_by]:order=='desc'?-1:1}},
            {$skip : skip},
            {$limit : pagelimit}
          ])
```